# $ A^2(t) - 5A(t) = 6I_n$ Show there exists $P : [0,1] \to GL_n(\mathbb R), \ C^1$ s.t. $\forall t \ \ P(t)A(0)P^{-1}(t) = A(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, continuity, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A : [0,1] \to M_n(\mathbb R)$ s.t. $\forall \ t \in [0,1], \
> A^2(t) - 5A(t) = 6I_n.$
>
> Show there exists $P : [0,1] \to GL_n(\mathbb R), \ C^1$ s.t. $\forall
> \ t \in [0,1],\ P(t)A(0)P^{-1}(t) = A(t)$

So $X^2 - 5X - 6 = \ (X-6)(X+1)$

Hence $\forall t \in [0,1] \ A(t)$ is diagonalizable with $6$ and $1$ as eigenvalues.

Then I would use the "continuity of the roots" of the carachteristic polynomial to say that the multiplicity of $6$ and $1$ the same for all $t$, so for all $t$, $A(t) \sim A(0)$.

How to proceed?

Comment: $A(t)(A(t)-5I_n)=6I_n=A(0)(A(0)-5I_n)$. Therefore $A(t)-5I_n$ and $A(0)-5I_n$ are invertible. You only need to show that $(A(t)-5I_n)(A(0)-5I_n)^{-1}$ is $C^1$ (implicit function theorem).

Comment: (This theorem is not in my curriculum so I suppose it had to be solved without)

Comment: I think you don't know well you curriculum. In any case, first understand the solution and then worry about superfluous considerations on what parts of the argument you would like to modify.

Comment: Is $A$ required to be $C^1$?

Comment: @Servaes Must be, although he didn't put it there. Otherwise, there is no hope for such $P$.

Comment: No I checked, it's not my curriculum and it was not at the time the exercise was given. That's why I put parentheses.

Comment: It is not precised that $A$ is $C^1$.

Comment: Imagine $A(t)=6I_n$ for $t\in[0,1/2]$ and $A(t)=-I_n$ for $t\in(1/2,1]$. It satisfies the equation. Can you have such a $P$ in this case?

Comment: About the implicit function theorem, it is not needed in my solution, actually. From $A\in C^1$ (or just continuous, but in that case you might need the theorem back) you can get $(A(t)-5I_n)(A(0)-5I_n)^{-1}\in C^1$.

Comment: @Orole I thought the same, otherwise the statement is false. Also, it seems unlikely that the implicit function theorem is not among the very first things in any mathematical curriculum.

Comment: even in the first two years? Is the theorem really necessary if $A$ is only continuous?

Comment: @Lucas Necessary, not. A theorem is never necessary, since it can always be replaced by its proof. It is only convenient since it allows me to be as lazy as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that $A(t)\in C^1$.

There are integers $p\geq 0,q\geq 0$ s.t. $p+q=n$ and $A(0)$ is similar to $diag(6I_p,-I_q)$. Note that $trace(A(t))$ is continuous and the eigenvalues $(\lambda_i(t)$ of $A(t)$ can be numbered in such a way that they are continuous functions of $A(t)$; consequently, for every $t$, $A(t)$ is also similar to  $diag(6I_p,-I_q)$.

More precisely $A(t)=6U(t)-V(t)$ where $U,V$ are projectors of trace $p,q$ s.t. $UV=VU=0$. From $7V=A^2-6A,42U=A^2+A$, we deduce that $U(t),V(t)$ are $C^1$. To show the existence of $P(t)$, it is enough to

(*) find a $C^1$ parametrization of a basis of $E(t)=\ker(U(t)-I_n)$, a vector subspace of dimension $p$, that is an element of the Grassmannian $G_{p,n}$.

Since $G_{p,n}$ is compact, it suffices to prove locally (*). Let $t_0\in[0,1)$. We may assume that $U(t)-I=\begin{pmatrix}P_{p,p}&Q_{p,q}\\R_{q,p}&S_{q,q}\end{pmatrix}$ where $rank(U(t_0)-I)=rank(S(t_0))=q$. Thus, locally, $S(t)$ is invertible and $\begin{pmatrix}x_p\\y_q\end{pmatrix}\in E(t)$ iff $y=-S^{-1}Rx$, that is

$E(t)=\{\begin{pmatrix}x\\-S(t)^{-1}R(t)x\end{pmatrix};x\in \mathbb{R}^p\}\in G_{p,n}$. Finally, the required $C^1$ parametrization is locally

$t\rightarrow \{\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\-S(t)^{-1}R(t)e_1\end{pmatrix},\cdots,\begin{pmatrix}e_p\\-S(t)^{-1}R(t)e_p\end{pmatrix}\}$.